# Parse string using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to parse 3 sections out of the following strings:

```
"Hello World 12 7" -> I want ["Hello World", "12", "7"]
"Goodbye -4 72" -> I want ["Goodbye", "-4", "72"]
```

The text part can have any number of words and both numbers can be negative.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are exactly the three sections you are after with this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method [`Regex.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) and regex [`(?i) (?![a-z])`](https://regex101.com/r/OUPrmJ/1).

Details:

- `(?i)` Case insensitive
- `(?!)` Negative lookahead, match space not followed by `[a-z]`

**C# code**:

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, "(?i) (?![a-z])");
```

Output:

```
["Hello World", "12", "7"]
["Goodbye", "-4", "72"]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/lF8H7e)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could match the values:

[`(?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )*(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)|-?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/JO7lrk/1)

That would match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Uppercase character followed by one or more lowercase characters and a whitespace
  - `)*` Close group and repeat zero or more times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Uppercase character followed by one or more lowercase characters
  - `)` Close group
  - `|` Or
  - `-?\d+` Optional dash followed by one or more digits
- `)` Close group

[Demo C#](http://rextester.com/NJUGG27459)